# Fetching and combine data from Api In Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, api, http, angular6

How to retrieve data from API and
For each user id returns his posts with their comments in one JSON object?

**posts** can be fetched from this API: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

and their **comments** from this API: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments

```
//Get User Posts And Comments
getUser() {
    this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts') && this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments')

    .subscribe(data => {
      this.posts = data;
    });

  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `forkJoin` to combine requests

```
let req1 = this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')  
let req2 = this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments')

forkJoin([req1,req2 ] )
   .subscribe(data => {
      this.posts = data;
});
```

Comment: Here data is an array of response1 and response2. As an alternative you could `.subscribe( ([dataPosts, dataComments]) => { this.posts = dataPosts; this.comments = dataComments;});` to access the responses.